# Group By causing bug after Database restore

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am working on a rather complex and time critical data conversion. 
This is achieved by using a Stored Procedure.

A recent change request required me to update this stored procedure. To do so in a safe manner, I have created a full schema dump including data and have imported this into two different schemas. One called 'original' and one called 'amended'.

Before updating the live database I am trying to compare the output of the original and amended database to identify the data that has been added and that none has been lost.

Unfortunately my test system is running MySQL v 5.7.12-0ubuntu-1 whereas my live server is a CentOS Server running 5.6.30.

A group clause in the original database (identical with live) is raising an issue (that does not exist on live). This error (1055  - Expression #5 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains non-aggregated column) makes total sense and is addressed in the revised database. I just want to run a comparison without having to install the exact same version of MySQL on this development server.

I have tried to remove `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` from my sql_mode parameter and have matched the sql_mode on both servers to only `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

Can anyone help? The query is below:

```
Insert into skeleton_football (
    sport_id,
    parent_event_id,
    event_id,
    event_part_id,
    back_outcome_id,
    lay_outcome_id,
    start_time,
    market_type,
    competition_name,
    event_name,
    event_part_name,
    outcome_name,
    outcome_value
)   
SELECT 
  sp.id as `sport_id`,
  if (ev.name is null, pev.id, null) as `parent_event_id`,
  ev.id as `event_id`,
  evp.id as `event_part_id`,
  oc.back_outcome_id as back_outcome_id,
  oc.lay_outcome_id as lay_outcome_id,
  #oc.param_float_1,
  #oc.param_float_2,
  #oc.param_float_3, 
  #oc.param_boolean_1, 
  #oc.param_string_1,
  #oc.param_participant_id_1,
  #oc.param_participant_id_2,
  #oc.param_participant_id_3,
  #oc.param_event_part_id_1,
  ev.start_time as start_time,
  sp.name as market_type,
  if (ev.name is null, pev.name, ev.name) as competition_name,
  if (sp.name = "football",concat(epah.name, " v ", epaa.name),ev.name) as event_name,
  evp.name as event_part_name,
  oct.name as outcome_name,
  get_outcome_value(
    oct.name,
    oc.param_participant_id_1,
    max(epah.id), 
    max(epah.name),
    max(epaa.id),
    max(epaa.name),
    opa.id,
    opa.name,
    oc.param_float_1, 
    oc.param_float_2,
    oc.param_boolean_1
  ) as outcome_value
FROM raw_event ev 
left join raw_event pev on pev.id = ev.parent_id
inner join raw_sport sp on ev.sport_id = sp.id
inner join config_events_filter cef on cef.sport_id = sp.id and (cef.competition_name is null or pev.name like cef.competition_name)
left join outcome_matched oc on ev.id = oc.event_id
inner join raw_event_part evp on evp.id = oc.event_part_id and evp.name in ("ordinary time", "whole match", "whole event")
cross join raw_participant_role prh on prh.name ="home"
cross join raw_participant_role pra on pra.name = "away"
cross join raw_participant_role pro on pro.name not in ("home", "away")
left join raw_event_participant_relation pera on pera.event_id = ev.id and pra.id = pera.participant_role_id
left join raw_event_participant_relation perh on perh.event_id = ev.id and prh.id = perh.participant_role_id 
left join raw_event_participant_relation pero on pero.event_id = ev.id and pro.id = pero.participant_role_id
left join raw_outcome_type oct on oc.type_id = oct.id
left join raw_participant epaa on pera.participant_id = epaa.id
left join raw_participant epah on perh.participant_id = epah.id
left join raw_participant epao on pero.participant_id = epao.id
#left join raw_participant epap on per.participant_id = epap.id and pr.name not in ("home", "away")
left join raw_participant opa on oc.param_participant_id_1 = opa.id 
where ev.start_time > date_sub('2016-05-11 14:00:00', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
and ev.start_time < date_add('2016-05-11 14:00:00', INTERVAL 2 DAY)
group by sp.id, ev.id, evp.id, oc.back_unique, if (sp.name = "football",concat(epah.name, " v ", epaa.name),ev.name)
having event_name is not null;
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're saying.  You removed `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` and the error still occurs?  Take a look at the procedure in the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES` table.  The `sql_mode` in effect when a procedure is defined is what will be used when the procedure is run.  Changing the server config after the fact won't help.

Comment: Thanks. The SQL Mode for this routine is simply `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`, so I'm still not clear why this grouping is an issue.